How to create for loop to return series of objects considering apostrophes to input into another function
Hi I have a function which looks like this...
for n in results[:10]:
    data_frame = mda.get_unified_series(
    SeriesEntry('nyse_vl'),
    SeriesEntry('useqin0016'),
    ......
   ).to_pd_data_frame()

And I have thousands of series entries from my list which makes it not feasible for me to write each ticker one by one.
As such I decided to create a function to return all elements in my list so i can input it inside the function.
def produce_list(list):
    final =[]
    for n in list:
        final.append("SeriesEntry(" + "'" + n + "'" +')')
    return final

But what it returns me is....
["SeriesEntry('nyse_vl')",
 "SeriesEntry('useqin0016')",
.....

When what I'm looking for is
SeriesEntry('nyse_vl'),
SeriesEntry('useqin0016'),
.....

Help please?

final.append(SeriesEntry(n))…!?

You don't want to produce source code text, you want to create a bunch of objects with a variable from a list. Enter Python list comprehensions:
[SeriesEntry(n) for n in list]

And then you want to pass this list of objects to a function as individual arguments. Enter argument unpacking:
mda.get_unified_series(*[SeriesEntry(n) for n in list])

For completeness:

Don't name a variable "list", choose a different name. list is the builtin list constructor, you shouldn't shadow its name.

For more efficiency, you can use a generator expression, which doesn't have to build the entire list and then unpack it, but will do it on the fly. But that's a micro-optimisation you don't need to worry too much about:
mda.get_unified_series(*(SeriesEntry(n) for n in list))



